# How can I set jquery cdn in global?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.3

I put jquery cdn in

> C:\xampp\htdocs\mysystem\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php

like this :

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    @yield('css')
</head>
<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    ...
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    ...
    @yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

So it can used from anywhere

But when executed this :

> C:\xampp\htdocs\mysystem\resources\views\users\index.blade.php

The code like this :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <section class="content-header">
        ...
    </section>
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
           ...
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

There exist error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Why there exist error? Whereas I had add jquery cdn in app.blade

Comment: Why my question downvote?

Comment: Simple answer is.... jQuery library must load before you can access it with your script. Order of script tags is important

Comment: @charlietfl, Do you mean the `<script src` is moved inside the head tag?

Comment: Not specifically , no. Simply means you can't use `$` until it is defined and it is defined in jQuery.js library. So jQuery.js must load before any code that depends on it

Comment: @freedomn-m modern best practices would suggest the opposite...put script tags in bottom of body and in proper dependency order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery is not yet loaded, because the content is inserted before jQuery.
You should move your javascript into the `scripts` section.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <section class="content-header">
        ...
    </section>
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
           ...
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

As many of the comments pointed out, you are not loading jquery before you call your own javascript. I would use the javascript section and set you pages up as below.

**layout**

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    @yield('css')
</head>
<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    @yield('content')
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    ...
    @yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

**blade template**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <section class="content-header">
        ...
    </section>
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
@endsection

@section('javascript')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
           ...
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```